# Let $ABCDE$ be a regular pentagon, Internal angle bisectors of $A$ and $B$ meet at $O$ then prove that $OC, OD, OE$ are also internal angle bisectors.

Tags: geometry

> Let $ABCDE$ be a regular pentagon, Internal angle bisectors of $A$ and $B$ meet at $O$ then prove that $OC, OD, OE$ are also internal angle bisectors.

I need a proof that involves a convincing geometry.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In $\Delta AOE$ and $\Delta AOB$, we have $EA=BA$, $\angle EAO=\angle BAO$ and $AO=AO$. Hence, $\Delta AOE\cong\Delta AOB$ by SAS. Similarly, $\Delta COB\cong\Delta AOB\cong\Delta AOE$, so $\angle OEA=\angle OCB=54^\circ$ (since $\angle OAB=\angle OBA=54^\circ$). Since the internal angles of a regular pentagon is $108^\circ$, we have that $EO$ and $CO$ are also angle bisectors.

From here, we can use the same argument to prove that $\Delta DOE\cong\Delta DOC$. In $\Delta DOE$ and $\Delta DOC$, we have $DE=DC$, $\angle DEO=\angle DCO$ and $EO=CO$. Hence, $\Delta AOE\cong\Delta AOB$ by SAS. This implies that $DO$ is an angle bisector too. Hence, we have proven that $AO, BO, CO, DO$ and $EO$ are angle bisectors of their respective angles.

[image]